# Prompts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to install software on centos 7 using ansible playbook through jenkins.

I am trying to call ansible playbook from jenkins for installing the software.

I am using vars_prompt in ansible playbook to pass some user-defined parameters, when i run the ansible playbook manually, it asks for prompts and runs successfully but when i build using jenkins it doesn't prompt for any inputs.

Pipeline:

```
node {
    ansiblePlaybook(
        installation: 'FirstAnsibleTest',
        inventory: '/etc/ansible/hosts',
        playbook: '/etc/ansible/install.yml',
        become: true,
        colorized: true,
        )
}
```

install.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:
   - name: "webusername"
     prompt: "Enter webusername"
   - name: "webpassword"
     prompt: "Enter webpassword"
     private: yes
  tasks:
   - import_tasks: /etc/ansible/roles/installe/tasks/main.yml
```

How can I make jenkins to ask for prompts that can be passed to the ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Jenkins launches the job as non-interactive manner, you need to pass `--extra-vars` with the variables and their value when calling the playbook (ex: `--extra-vars 'webusername=foo webpassword=bar'`).

This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html).

> Prompts for individual `vars_prompt` variables will be skipped for any
>   variable that is already defined through the command line `--extra-vars`
>   option, or when running from a non-interactive session (such as cron
>   or Ansible Tower). See Passing Variables On The Command Line in the
>   [/Variables/](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) chapter.

For the password I understand that is not possible to pass it directly but you can for instance use an environment variable.